# Parse "45,978" to double value

Tags: java, csv

I want to parse `"45,978"` to double which is read from a `*.csv`. Right now I am doing:

```
double P_current = Double.parseDouble(priceList.get(j));
```

However I am getting a number format exception for this string input:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45,978"
```

I know that I could change all the `,` in my csv file to a `.` which would probably work. However I do not want that, because I need the comma in this file. Is there any ways to parse this to double `as-it-is`?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Is that number supposed to represent `45978` or `45.978`?

Comment: `priceList.get(j) = priceList.get(j).replace(",",".");`.

Comment: @assylias I am working on a german system `, equals .`, so it is `45.978`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double parsed = Double.parseDouble(priceList.get(j).replace(',', '.'));
```

Or you could also use a [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with the appropriate locale or symbols.

Comment: Dont do that at work :) Locale independent code is bad thing.

Comment: @MariuszS With what we know about the context, we can't tell if being locale-dependant or locale-independant is good or bad. That's why this answer suggests both solutions. Most of the time, a simple, effective and to-the-point solution is better than an overengineered solution that solves non-existent problems.

Comment: @MariuszS If the CSV format is specified as locale-independent, and that is how it *should* be specified, then the solution must be locale-independent as well.

Comment: For me this is still more readable if we read german CSV file with explicit Locale.GERMAN than making mess in code like `.replace(',', '.')` - code like this need to be commented, because there is no context about german locale in it.

Comment: @MariuszS Quite to the contrary, looking at the CSV you can immediately tell what processing it needs in terms of characters, not locales. If you saw an opaque `Locale.GERMAN` in the code, you couldn't be positive what processing that will result in, *even if you were German*.

Comment: I always love Genius Solutions To Simple Problems - bit.ly/KqRW8v :) And still prefer to know than CSV has German data without looking into it. This makes code clean and readable. Cheers.

Comment: @MariuszS OK, maybe I'm biased---my country is not as big and well-organized as Germany, and when I see `Locale.CROATIAN` (well, such a constant doesn't even exist), I haven't got the first idea what will happen :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to replace anything, you can use [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) and [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) with [Locale#GERMAN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#GERMAN):

```
try {
   NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
   double number = nf.parse("45,978").doubleValue();
} catch(ParseException e) { }
```

If you want to be locale-independent, you can simply replace `,` with `.` to get the format that `Double#parseDouble` works with.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the appropriate [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) according to your locale :

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
Number number = format.parse("45,978");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

If your numbers are not from the English locale. Change the locale to a proper one:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
Number number = format.parse("45,978");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

See more on `NumberFormat` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).